# How to make a SetOnClickListener only happening when its EditText's are different from zero

Tags: android, null, onclicklistener

I want to make a calculator that uses the button Add to take 2 different EditText's and add them, showing on a Toast. But when I click directly on the button without typing any value, the app crashes. I would be very glad to hear a solution to this. I tried with an if comparing with null. Here's the code:

```
if(num1 != null && num2 != null){

    som.setOnClickListener(         
        new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


            Double valor1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
            Double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());

            Double Soma = valor1+valor2;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"A soma é: "+Soma, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                    }
    });
}
```

Comment: you dont need an if condition for setting a listener in this case. secondly, you have to check the values in the edittext [num1.getText() & num2.getText()] and not the reference for edittext (num1 & num2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `if(! num1 .getEditableText().toString().matches("") && !num2 .getEditableText().toString().matches(""))` in your onClick method

Answer (score 0):

you should use num1.getText().toString()!=null no num1!=null and you should set inputtype of edittext from type of number

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
if(num1 != null && num2 != null){

    som.setOnClickListener(         
        new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){                        
            Double valor1=0;
            Double valor2=0;
            if(!num1.getText().toString().equals(""))
              valor1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
            if(!num2.getText().toString().equals(""))
              valor2= Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());

            Double Soma = valor1+valor2;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"A soma é: "+Soma, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking editText for null

```
if(num1 != null && num2 != null){
```

you should check the values you will get from editTexts.

```
if (num1.getText().toString() != null && !num1.getText().toString().equals("")&&
  num2.getText().toString() != null && !num2.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
 som.setOnClickListener(         
        new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


            Double valor1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
            Double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());

            Double Soma = valor1+valor2;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"A soma é: "+Soma, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give if condition like this

```
if(num1 != "" && num2 != ""){
}
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: It goes wrong because you can't compare using the equal sign a string with a null object, only with other string

Comment: Hi Gabriel, i run this code. its working.....
String num1="test";String num2=""; 
if (num1 != "" && num2 != "") {

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, soma é: " + num1 + " " + num2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in else condition",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}